# Catch Number Format Exception

Tags: java, exception

I am working on a Calculator project for my java class that requires me to use exceptions. When an operator is entered into the calculator followed by anything other than a number, it should catch the NumberFormatException and display an error message saying "Invalid non-numeric operand." Instead, it shows a different error.

This is the code I have to catch the error:

```
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   input = kb.nextLine();
}
```

And I have this to display the message:

```
public class NumberFormatException extends IllegalArgumentException
{
   public NumberFormatException()
   {
      super("Invalid non-numeric operand.");
   }
}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at Calculator.doCalculation(Calculator.java:59)
        at CalculatorTest.main(CalculatorTest.java:25)
```

But I am unsure of what to do from here as I don't quite understand the exception. I apologize if this is simple, I am very new to java. Please help, thank you!

Comment: What is the "different error" being shown?

Comment: Post all your code and the error you get

Comment: You have defined your own `Exception` type, but not thrown it (most likely).  The `NumerFormatException` which gets thrown when parsing numbers is an _internal_ class.  You will probably need to delete your own `NumberFormatException` class, and deal with `System.out.println`-ing the alert you need when _that_ gets thrown.

Comment: Can you please post the "different error" you're getting?

Comment: What's on Calculator.java line 59?

Answer (score 1):

Your Exception is ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException . This is not related to the format of Strings. It is about trying to access array elements that do not exist.

Look at line 59 as the message indicates. You haven't shared this with us, so you're on your own from here.